# Автоматически подхватывать vault-переменные из роли?

Tags: ansible

В первый раз вдруг понадобилось подключить vault-переменные в роли. (Из host_vars подключается без проблем)

Создал в папке roles/myrole/vars/vault.yml, положил в него переменную и... при выполнении скрипта получаю ошибку "переменная не определена".

При этом рядом кладу файл roles/myrole/vars/main.yml (незашифрованные) и они прекрасно оттуда подхватываются.

Я что-то делаю не так? Или автоматом vault-переменные не подхватываются?

Прыгал по ссылкам в документации по разделам [Roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles.html), [Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html) -- никаких подсказок не нашёл. Перечитал даже раздел [Best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html) про типовую структуру папок -- любопытно, что и там нет примера, что в vars роли vault.yml был.

Версия ансибл -  2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До сих пор (включая Ansible 2.4) в папках `myrole/defaults` и `myrole/vars` автоматически загружаются только файлы `main.yml`.

Можно последить за [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14248).

Если переменные разбиты не несколько файлов, то в таски роли добавляют:

```
- include_vars: my_custom_vars.yml
```

P.S. про vault внутри роли совсем непонятно – зачем? роли должны быть легкими для переиспользования – как это делать, если к ней прицеплен зашифрованный файл?

Comment: Формально, я понимаю, что пароль может быть переопределён на уровне хоста, однако там такая специфическая переменная определена, которую поменять крайне сложно -- она одинаковая везде, поэтому и возникла мысль её на уровне роли определить. Ну скажем, там лежит пароль, которым vault-файлы шифруются - а роль разворачивает этот файл для нужных серверов и хостов. Аналогия понятна?

Comment: Не очень. Можно, к примеру в `myrole/vars/main.yml` добавить `mypass: "{{ vault_mypass | default('nopass') }}"`, что роль не сломает – будет `nopass` по умолчанию (и при этом у `mypass` будет высокий приоритет); но в тоже время можно в зашифрованный `inventory/groups_vars/all/vault.yml` добавить `vault_mypass: sEcReT`, что заставит для всех хостов использовать уже секретный пароль.

Comment: Кстати, хороший вариант!